# Created a NuGet pipeline in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

I have created a NuGet pipeline as my build pipeline in my Azure devops. AM getting some error while building the pipeline

[image: error message]

[image: pipeline]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try checking the `Restore NuGet Packages` option in the build tasks. Sometimes the retore nuget option need to be check in VSBuild task too.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Install-Package EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging -Version 5.0.505